# JBoss in Mac OSX won't accept connections from VMware IE10

Tags: eclipse, macos, jboss, vmware, internet-explorer-10

I am runnning JBoss server () on Mac OSX on port 8080 from an STS(Eclipse) project via `http://localhost/project/home`.

I can open any browser on the Mac and connect to my project with no issues.

However, when I run Win7 in VMware on the same machine and attempt the same URL using IE10, I get "This page can't be displayed".  "Fix connection problems" returns the message :

> "The remote device or resource won't accept the connection"

I can ping from my Win7 over to my local IP# with no trouble.  I do not find a "standalone.xml" anywhere on my hard drive. My Win7 etc/hosts file contains a listing for my OSX IP and hostname.

I added `-d 0.0.0.0` to my JBoss run configuration in STS(Eclipse).  No change.

After much googling I believe that I merely need to change some setting in JBoss so that it will respond to my Win7.  However, many of the responses I find are too cryptic to understand for a JBoss newb.

Can someone advise me?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: P.S. forgot to add in JBoss version is 5.0, STS version is 3.3.0, OSX is 10.7.5, VMware is 4.1.4, Windows 7 is ver 6.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to let the jboss listen to an interface is "-b" for bind to.

So you should start the Jboss with this parameter to listen to all interfaces:

```
-b 0.0.0.0
```

And make sure that the firewall has opend the Port 8080, as well ;)

If you use the JBoss Tools in Eclipse to manage your Jboss, make right click in the "Servers" view on the Server and select "Open" in the context menü.
This should open a launch editor which allowes you to change all the polling, managing and deployment stuff.
There is a field "Hostname". Change this to "0.0.0.0" and it will configure the launch config correctly for you. I think in newest version of the tools there is a checkbox "Listen on all interface" or so. When this checkbox is there, enable it and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for the rapid answer.  Unfortunately that was a typo in my question; the option I really added was the correct one, -b 0.0.0.0.  My OSX firewall (ipfw) is set to allow port 8080.  Thanks for the help but I don't think this is the issue.  If the port were blocked by the firewall, would I be able to ping it?

Comment: No you can only ping ports where you will get an ICMP Echo response. The http connector of the jboss is TCP and will not echo. Have you tried to open the app on the jboss host over his ip address instead of "localhost" to ensure that it's listening to all interfaces?

Comment: OK I had not tried that, but it works! If I use <ip>:8080/project/home, it opens right up.  So is this a sign that I have something wrong in my Windows /etc/hosts file? I double checked it, the entry is merely '<ip#> localhost'. Thank you very much, at least this way I can access my site for testing locally.

Comment: Argh, you try to change localhost to a other ip then your loop back device? And to open the remote app over localhost? Why? You can do something like ip myappserver and then call your server over "myappserver" or call it directly over the ip address.

Comment: :) "Argh" is what many people say to me.  I wonder what could be wrong with so many people... thanks again for your advice and patience LOL - changing my hosts file to <ip> thickSkulled works fine, I can now see 'http://thickSkulled:8080/project/home' :)